# How to crawl the website using java without going to infinite loop

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to crawl the social media data using java and Jsoup. Firstly,I'm giving one url and trying to crawl the data.

But it is going to infinite loop.In that base url,there are lots of child url's. And those child url's are referring to some other base url's.And this process is going on to infinite url's.

How can I limit the url's by preventing infinite loop.Can anyone please help me out regarding this.

Comment: Keep track of the URLs you've visited, don't visit a visited URL again.

Comment: I'm not visiting to the same url which I had already visited.It is going to some other base url.This is the issue I'm facing.

Comment: So where is the infinite loop? Are you saying that you are simply finding more URLs than you want to crawl? (That's not the same thing)

Comment: It's not infinite. It's just more then what you expected. Put some limits, and break out.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I'll try by  keeping limits.

Answer (score 0):

Add all the URL's you have visited to a linkedlist(or something like that) and when you cant find any more URL's that aint in the list, you can finish the loop.

Check also that the basename is correct by

```
  private String basename="www.example.com";

  public boolean compareBasename(String url){
      URI uri = new URI(url);
      String domain = uri.getHost();
      return domain.equals(basename);
 }
```

And compare the string domain to the basename of the page you are checking

Answer (score 0):

use a Set to keep your urls:

```
 Set<String> already_visited=new HashSet<String>()
```

Then test each time:

```
 if (!already_visited(new_url)) // do what you want
```

and insert it

```
already_visited.add (new_url)
```

Then, you wont have cycles